# How to clone the div with button properties?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to clone the entire div with the button properties. Is there any problem with my current code `$("#dynamicsegment").clone().appendTo("#copieddiv")?`

```
 <div id="dynamicsegment">
      <button type="button" id="start">Star</button>
      <button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
 </div>

    <script>
      $('#start').click(function(){
          $( "#stopdiv" ).hide();
          $( "#startdiv" ).show();
       }); 
    $('#stop').click(function(){
          $( "#stopdiv" ).show();
          $( "#startdiv" ).hide();
       });
 
    </script>
```

Comment: One problem will be that you will have multiple elements with the same id, after you have cloned, and that is not good, ID has to be unique

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: you have to use class for button click if you want to same behaviour after cloned button append.

Answer (score 0):

The clone function copies all the properties (such as id, class, custom attribute) of the destination object. But its event handlers are not copied.

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the code but I do not suggest to use id on cloned element because ID is unique.

```js
$('#start').click(function(){
    $( "#stopdiv" ).hide();
    $( "#startdiv" ).show();
}); 
$('#stop').click(function(){
   $( "#stopdiv" ).show();
   $( "#startdiv" ).hide();
});

$('#button').on('click', function(){
  $(".cloned-element:last").clone().appendTo(".cloned-element:last");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cloned-element" id="dynamicsegment">
     <button type="button" id="start">Star</button>
     <button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>

<button id="button">Dublicate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#start').click(function(){
  $("#dynamicsegment").clone().appendTo('body');
  $( "#stopdiv" ).hide();
  $( "#startdiv" ).show();
}); 
$('#stop').click(function(){
  $( "#stopdiv" ).show();
  $( "#startdiv" ).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="dynamicsegment">
                  <button type="button" id="start">Star</button>
                  <button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css ID's to classes. Also when you append your new element, check that it exists. In this example, I am assuming there is already a `.cloned-elemnent`

```js
$(function(){
    
    var $template = $('.dynamicsegment').clone()
    
    $(template).appendTo(".cloned-element:last")

})
```

Let me know if this helps :)